# Regexp - match tag 'a' without http:// in href

Tags: php, regex

I have for example these "a" tags:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/products/foo">Foo product</a>
<a href="/articles/bar">Bar article</a>
```

I use this pattern:

```
/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU
```

This expression returns to me both tags (foo product and bar article).
Can you help me please how to make an expression that returns only tag "bar article"?

Thank you.

EDIT:

@Avinash Raj thank you for the tip.

These result of the pattern works for me:

```
/^.*<a\s[^>]*href="http:\/\/.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\1[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/miU
```

Comment: use a negative lookahead. But really you should be parsing the html

Comment: I’m just going to leave this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @user What would be the expected output?

Comment: don't parse HTML with regexes - it's not a regular language. Use a special parser instead

Comment: @user3468684 see http://regex101.com/r/sQ0kW4/6

Comment: That regular expression is quite complex, which makes it difficult to read and maintain. Please don't ignore the advice against using regular expressions, it's there for a reason! An approach using parser may be longer but at least it is fairly self-documenting, which is _much_ more important. Please take a look at my answer and if you have any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DOM parser, such as [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php
$site = <<<'EOT'
<a href="http://www.domain.com/products/foo">Foo product</a>
<a href="/articles/bar">Bar article</a>
EOT;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($site);

$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    $scheme = parse_url($href, PHP_URL_SCHEME);
    if (!isset($scheme)) {            
        echo $a->textContent;   // output: Bar article
    }
}
```

Loop through each `<a>` element. Parse the url, using [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). If the scheme isn't set in the `href` attribute, then echo the content. Of course, what you actually want to do with the element is entirely up to you.

Comment: Ok, this is the best solution. Easy to read and more useful than regexp. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a href="(.*)<\/a>
```

with preg_match_all and then get the last result out of the $matches array with

```
$web =   '<a href="http://www.domain.com/products/foo">Foo product</a>
          <a href="/articles/bar">Bar article</a>';
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"(.*)<\/a>/", $web , $matches); 

print_r( $matches[0][count($matches[0])-1]); // should only give Bar article
```

BUT like someone already pointed: do not use regex to search through DOM. Use DOM parser instead!